# android media player not working properly

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have two buttons when click on first then it plays a sound, if click on second button then it play different sound but i am having a problem that if I click first button then it play sound but after it if I click second button then it that button does not work? what can be the problem.

Comment: Please provide code that you think is causing issue.

Comment: when one song is playing and you clicked on second button.. You need to stop/release the old media player before starting the new one...